# turn notification on automatically on ios 8

Tags: xcode, push-notification, ios8.1

my app is handling notification like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

and the code works but the notification pop up doesn't show and in order to get them ones need to enter the notification settings and allow notifications.

Is there a way to force IOS 8 to pop the notification automatically after installation like in IOS 6 & 7?

Comment: Why do you want to send notifications if the user doesn't want to receive them?

Comment: @Abizern it's not if the user doesn't want them. you know how when you install an application that has push notifications it asks if you allow it? and then you can decide if you want it or not... in IOS 8 my app doesn't show that initial window so the user doesn't knoq there is an option for notifications.